# How to show flow of vector field $(-f(y))$ is $\phi_{-t}(x)$ where $\phi_{t}(x)$ is the flow of $(f(y))$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a locally Lipschitz vector field for Initial Value Problem (IVP) $\dot{y} = f(y)$ with $y(0)=x$, where $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open.

> Definition: Let $\phi : \Omega \rightarrow E $ be the solution to the IVP $\dot{y} = f(y)$ with $y(0)=x$ where $\Omega=\{(t,x) \mid x \in E , t \in I_x\}$ and $I \in \mathbb{R}$ is an interval which includes $0$.

Prove flow of vector field $(-f(y))$ is $\phi_{-t}(x)$ where $\phi_{t}(x)$ is the flow of $(f(y))$?

My try:

When $u(t)$ is the solution to the IVP, it satisfies the following:

$$
u(t)=x+\int_0^t f(u(s))ds
$$

Now let $\phi_t(x)$ be the solution so

$$
\phi_t(x)=x+\int_0^t f(\phi_s(x))ds \tag{1}
$$

Now suppose we have $\dot{y} = -f(y)$ with $y(0)=x$ as our IVP. Let $\phi'_t(x)$ be the solution to the new IVP so

$$
\phi'_t(x)=x+\int_0^t -f(\phi'_s(x))ds
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
\phi'_t(x)=x+\int_t^0 f(\phi'_s(x))ds \tag{3}
$$

How would you show $\phi'_t(x)=\phi_{-t}(x)$ from $(3)$ and $(1)$.

Comment: For each $x\in E$ we have, by the formula for the derivative of the composite function, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\phi_{-t}(x)\bigr\lvert_{t=0}=-f(\phi_0(x))=-f(x).$$

Comment: I understood your point but could you please manipulate $(3)$ to show the result?

Comment: One does not need to manipulate $(3)$ here: since at each $x \in E$ the derivative at time $t = 0$ of the solution $t \mapsto \phi_{-t}(x)$ equals $-f(x)$, that (local) flow is just the (local) flow of the vector field $-f$ (and there is no need whatsoever to repeat the proof of the existence of a solution to an IVP).